# Azure function working in local but not after uploading to azure

Tags: azure, azure-functions, signalr, azure-signalr

I'm new with azure functions and azure as whole.

I'm using azure functions for interacting with a SignalR service for usage in a xamarin forms app. I borrowed the azure function code from docs.[MSDocs on serverless signalR service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-signalr/signalr-quickstart-azure-functions-csharp)

Worked well in local (tested the web client provided in the docs, And also a simple console app).

But when the function was moved to azure. Initially I faced CORS error fixed those and then faced 502. Could not debug or find the root cause. After few hours of browsing found that azure itself provides a template for signalR serverless connection.

[image]

Used the template, configured the app settings with signalR endpoints (I have set the app setting for `AzureSignalRConnectionString`).

Still facing 502 error, . **How can I get it to work? Or How do I find out the root cause for the failure.**

Negotiate function code:

index.js

```js
module.exports = async function (context, req, connectionInfo) {
    context.res.body = connectionInfo;
};
```

Function.json

```json
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "anonymous",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "methods": [
        "post"
      ],
      "name": "req"
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "res"
    },
    {
      "type": "signalRConnectionInfo",
      "name": "connectionInfo",
      "hubName": "messaage",
      "connectionStringSetting": "AzureSignalRConnectionString",
      "direction": "in"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: did you add AzureSignalRConnectionString in azure portal ?

Comment: S I did ADD it to the portal. @NAS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SignalR Service needs a **URL** to access Function App when you're using SignalR Service trigger binding.
[image]
The URL format: `<Function_App_URL>/runtime/webhooks/signalr?code=<API_KEY>`. Explanation: The `Function_App_URL` can be found on Function App's Overview page and The `API_KEY` is generated by Azure Function. You can get the API_KEY from `signalr_extension` in the App keys blade of Function App.

And if you are very new to this, here is a step by step article to follow: https://github.com/aspnet/AzureSignalR-samples/tree/master/samples/BidirectionChat

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I'll check this and let you know.

Comment: Have you solve your problem? @Error280MonkeyFound

Comment: Hi, yes I solved my issue by completely removing my azure functions and recreating them. Earlier function app had a runtime error. Something was messed up in that app, as I used both portal and vs code to publish functions.